# Restricting tbody to maximum height?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I'd like to enforce a `max-height` policy on a table's `tbody` with `overflow` set to `auto`, so that a scrollbar only shows up when a table gets too tall.

Is there a way to limit the height of a `tbody` element within a `table`, in this way?

My table of interest is dynamically inserted within a cell in a larger table, which is contained within a Bootstrap panel container. Doing the following kind of code did not work:

```
html = "";
html += "<p>";
html += "<table class=\"sortable target_detail_sortable\" style=\"width:100%;\" id=\"my_div_table\">";
html += "<thead>";
// populate header cells
html += "</thead>";
html += "<tbody style=\"max-height:300px; overflow:auto;\">";
// populate body cells
html += "</tbody>";
html += "</table>";
html += "</p>";
$("#my_div").html(html);
```

Any usable advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: From RFC 1942 - HTML Tables page 19, which introduced tables to HTML in 1996: "If the table has a large number of rows in the body, user agents may choose to use a scrolling region for the table body sections." Incredibly no browser has ever implemented such scrolling regions, so no you can't except within the limitations described by @GodisGood's answer.

Comment: I must have really upset someone! So sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set a fixed or maximum height on any table elements. [The `height` property is only treated as a minimum height.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout)

You *can* add `display: block` to your `tbody`. Since it's no longer one of the [`table-*` display types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display) in that case, that *will* make it take the height. However, since the `tbody` is no longer a `table-row-group`, you'll essentially end up with an implicit table inside it again. So any columns in any other `thead`, `tbody` or `tfoot` elements will no longer line up with that scrollable `tbody`.

Apart from the column mismatching, though, this does make it *almost* work in all the latest browsers except IE. You should be able to fix the remaining issues yourself.

I have no idea how to fix it in IE, though. I did come across ["Pure CSS Scrollable Table with Fixed Header"](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html), but that's rather out-dated, since both of his solutions work in IE6, but break horribly in IE7 and IE8 (in different ways too). They *do* work in IE's Quirks mode, though, so if you desperately need it, that might be your only option.